# Standard functions in R like substr is debugged which I am not interested

Tags: r, debugging

I have a big R program and somewhere in middle of a function, I put a `browser()` to debug the same. However, there is a pain with this debugging as even standard R functions like `substr`, `regexpr`, `nchar` are all getting debugged which I am not interested in. Please suggest how to stop this and debug only what I wrote in the function, but not the standard R functions.

Suppose you have a string

```
S = "ABCD,12345"
```

I want the result 12345 which is a substring of S after the character ','.  I use the below command:

```
substr(S, regexpr(",", S) + 1, nchar(S))
```

Command is correct and does well. But which debugging, the main function, this `substr`, `regexpr`, `nchar` are also getting debugged which is waste of time for me.

Comment: Not the question but `sub(".*,", "", S)` is more readable

Comment: It seems like you are `step`ping into each function, usually by having used the `s` command. Using the `n` command within debug mode should run each nested function without stepping into the function. Note that if you use `s` once, every `run` command (usually just clicking enter)  will use `s` until another command is used.

Comment: @Oliver, thanks for the comment. You are right!!! it resolved my problem. Thank you once again.

Comment: Glad i could help. I'll add the comment as a small answer for others who experience similar problems. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are stepping into each function, usually by having used the s command. Using the n command within debug mode should run each nested function without stepping into the function. Note that if you use s once, every run command (usually just clicking enter) will use s until another command is used.

R also has some more intricate tools for debugging. In Hadley's *free* online book [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html) there is a great chapter about debugging in R (Chapter 22). For more in-depth knowledge about debugging in R, i can highly recommend this chapter.